# Add CodeMirror to a MediaWiki page

Tags: mediawiki, codemirror

I know how to implement CodeMirror to a regular page but I have no idea how to do it on a MediaWiki webpage. I've tried adding the "codemirror.js" file the same way I added other scripts that I am using on the page but I get the error that "CodeMirror" is not defined when it is being initialized. In the code below shows how I added my previous scripts and the "codemirror.js".

```
$wgResourceModules['ext.SpecialRobotExp'] = array('scripts' => array(
    'module/PID.js', 'module/grid.js', 'module/saveFile.js', 'module/codemirror.js'
),
```

What I need is to know where to save the codemirror.js file and how to load it to the page on a MediaWiki webpage.

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve? What do you mean by "adding codemirror to a MediaWiki webpage"? How does your current (full) code looks like?

Comment: The full code is very modulized, it's a wiki-based remote laboratory for mobile robots platform in my school. I've been working on it for only a couple of months. The actual pages don't have a head tag, all the external files are linked in different files as the sample code I posted. I've managed to link the codemirror files now, however, it won't let me type on the editor.